# How to slide in video and auto play at the same time with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I would like to slide a video in from the left on click of a button and auto play at the same time. In my jsfiddle I've used a youtube video but in my site I will be using HTML5 video.

I've tried using the following code but the video comes up with an error when it should be auto playing. I want the video to then pause when it slides back out on click.

So slide in from left- play, slide out to left - pause.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

   <div class="content-wrapper"
         <a href="#" id="play-video">Play Video</a>
   </div>    

   <div class="full-video">
         <iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/vIu85WQTPRc" frameborder="0"   
   allowfullscreen></iframe>    
    </div>  

</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
z-index: 1;
}

.content-wrapper {
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
background: red;
bottom: -90px;
width: 100%;
-webkit-transition: bottom 1s;
-moz-transition: bottom 1s;
transition: bottom 1s;    
}

#play-video {
position: absolute;
background-color: blue;
z-index: 999;
cursor: pointer;
}

.full-video {
position: absolute;
left: -600px;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-transition: left 1s;
-moz-transition: left 1s;
transition: left 1s;  
}

.full-video iframe {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%; 
}
```

JS

```
var clicked=false;
$("#play-video").on('click', function(){
if(clicked)
{
    clicked=false;
    $(".full-video").css({"left": "-600px"});
    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();
}
else
{
    clicked=true;
    $(".full-video").css({"left": "0"});
    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=0";
    ev.preventDefault();
}
});
```

Here are some jsfiddle's

Just slide in … http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/58/
Slide in and code from above… http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/59/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/8ZFMJ/60/)

You werent using a correctly formed querystring, you were starting it with an ampersand (`&`) not a `?`, in addition, you were setting `autoplay=0/1` the wrong way around.

Updated jQuery:

```
var clicked=false;
var src=$("#video")[0].src;
$("#play-video").on('click', function(){
    if(clicked)
    {
        clicked=false;
        $(".full-video").css({"left": "-600px"});
        $("#video")[0].src = src;
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        clicked=true;
        $(".full-video").css({"left": "0"});
        $("#video")[0].src = src+"?autoplay=1";
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, is there a way to make it pause at that spot when you close it and then when you reopen it starts playing from that point again?

Comment: I've updated the code with a slight correction. Due to the fact you're simply loading the video in an iFrame and not fetching the video object itself, you arent able to pause/resume in the way you'd like.

Comment: I've just used iframe for jsfiddle purpose but say I were using HTML5 video would this work the same way? If it were HTML5 video would I be able to pause/resume?

Comment: It would be more than possible, you'd just fetch the HTML5 video element and call `.pause()` or `.play()` e.g. `$("#myVideo").get(0).paused ? $("#myVideo").get(0).play() :$("#myVideo").get(0).pause();`

Comment: Would you mind just integrating that into my existing JS just so I know how to apply it? Many thanks for this I'm not great with JS.